# Where can I find the Distributions Palette?

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distributions, palettes

I was watching the ["Statistics: Modeling with Statistical Distribution" Training Course](http://www.wolfram.com/training/videos/DAT016/) and in one of the slides, the following image showed up. Does anybody know if this palette is available and where can it be found?

[image: Distributions Palette]

Comment: For the record, this shows up at about 15:07 in the video. The [lecturer](http://blog.wolfram.com/author/roger-germundsson/) probably made it for his own use but did not think to share it in the video. Nice palette.

Comment: I saw this lecture, too a few years ago. After that I downloaded the palette..I could swear the author provided a link for download but I can't find it anymore on the website :(

Comment: [This blog](http://blog.wolfram.com/2013/02/01/the-ultimate-univariate-probability-distribution-explorer/) may have what you're looking for.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries Could you post that as an answer? So the question doesn't remain unanswered ...

Comment: @belisariushassettled OK, done. It isn't actually what was asked for though.

Comment: I believe I've found a copy of this palette lying around in my files, but I'm not sure if it's okay to post it. In any case, the palette is missing a number of distributions that were introduced after version 8(?), so a revamp of the palette would probably be needed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a [Wolfram blog](http://blog.wolfram.com/2013/02/01/the-ultimate-univariate-probability-distribution-explorer/) by Oleg Marichev and Michael Trott which has an accompanying CDF demonstration (that can be downloaded [here](http://blog.wolfram.com/data/uploads/2013/02/ProbabilityDistributionExplorer.zip)). This CDF can be used to explore distributions and their multitude of properties.

It isn't the palette you described (it also doesn't paste a function template as the original palette probably did) but it may be useful nevertheless.

[image]